# Widget confirmação de ação é possível?

Tags: java, android, widget

Tenho que colocar um AlertDialog para confirmar se o usuário quer mesmo realizar determinada ação, é simples fazer isso em uma activity ou fragment só que estou com problemas para fazer isso no widget, tentei fazer mas só estou obtendo erros como retorno.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
```

Que me retorna o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>
> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application
>
> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
>   window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei a solução para o meu problema a todos que tiverem o msm problema aqui esta a [solução](https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/04/06/android-display-a-dialog-from-an-appwidget/).